# Java Fatal in console

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

Ok so im new to making mods but i've setup the eclipse project and everything but i wanted to do a quick test to make sure it worked in minecraft. But in the console i keep getting a fatal error.
Any one know why?

```
[00:15:28] [Client thread/FATAL]: Error executing task
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at net.minecraft.util.Util.runTask(Util.java:23) [Util.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.runGameLoop(Minecraft.java:1070) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:380) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:116) [Main.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_261]
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(GradleStartCommon.java:97) [start/:?]
    at GradleStart.main(GradleStart.java:26) [start/:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Comment: I'm not a modder, but it looks like in some of your mod code you are trying to get an array element that has a higher index than the size of your array. AKA you are doing something like arr[37] on an array of length 10 or something.

Comment: Could you post the _relevant_ code for your mod?